# Azure search: Japanese search for Katakana and Hiragana

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have created search index with ja.microsoft analyzer and it works fine as far as I am searching for characters in katkana. But when Hiragana character is used search does not work and no search results are returned.

Ex:
Searching names in Hiragana can not hit names in Katakana, and vice versa:​
To hit "姥谷 キツ"(the name is in Katakana), searching "きつ" (in Hiragana) though. it fails to get it.​
To hit "元廣 あえか" (phonetic chars in Katakana), searching "アエカ" though, it fails to get it.​

Does Azure search support any analyzer which supports all writing schemes (Hiragana, Kankana, Kanji etc) or I need to use some other technique for this?

Answer (score 0):

Neither the Lucene nor the Microsoft Japanese analyzers generate katakana tokens for hiragana or vice-versa. The analyzer will create tokens for the given syllabary.

You can use the [analyze API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer) to see what tokens get generated for a particular string.

For instance, calling the analyze API with this input:

```
{
  "text": "元廣 あえか",
  "analyzer": "ja.microsoft"
}
```

returns:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://service-name.search.windows.net/$metadata#Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2019_05_06.AnalyzeResult",
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "元廣",
            "startOffset": 0,
            "endOffset": 2,
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "あえか",
            "startOffset": 3,
            "endOffset": 6,
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```